# How to get value whenever clicked on one "selectRadioButton"?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have button "Resize", I want that when I click on this button so that It's will call resizeDroplet(flavorId) method with flavorId that I got from when i choose one radioButton (selectItems)

I try below code, but I cannot get flavorId. How can I get it?

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="#{flavorId}" 
                  value="#{flavorBean.flavor.flavorID}"
                  layout="grid" columns="1">                      
   <f:selectItems value="#{flavorBean.listFlavors()}" var="c" 
                  itemLabel="#{c.getFlavorName()}"
                  itemValue="#{c.getFlavorID()}"/>

 </p:selectOneRadio>

 <p:commandButton value="Resize" id="resize" 
                  actionListener="#{dropletBean.resizeDroplet(flavorId)}" />
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about how JSF works ?

Comment: No, I just confused How can i get flavorId to pass it into my backing bean as example above.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the example from primefaces

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml